# DbSet LINQ query to inner collection does not throw an Argumentexception

Tags: entity-framework, linq, dbcontext, dbset

I met this for me kind of strange behavior and wonder what is behind that it works how it works.

```
_dbContext.MyDbSet.Where(setItem =>
    setItem.InnerCollection.All(...)
).ToList()
```

This piece of code works fine even if the InnerCollection is null. Surprise for me is, that both these pieces throw ArgumentNullException on the inner collection.

```
_dbContext.MyDbSet.Local.Where(setItem =>
    setItem.InnerCollection.All(...)
).ToList()
```

---

```
_dbContext.MyDbSet.ToList().Where(setItem =>
    setItem.InnerCollection.All(...)
).ToList()
```

Can anybody explain me how is this possible? Is there any `null` constrol behind the DbSet?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is very simple:

when using

```
_dbContext.MyDbSet.Where(setItem =>
    setItem.InnerCollection.All(...)
).ToList()
```

EF generates a JOIN statement and filtering is performed on the database and therfore no `ArgumentNullException` is raised.

While when calling `Local` or `ToList()` before filtering all your entities are loaded from the database and get filtered in-memory. Therefore in this versions the lists are null if you do not include the corresponding navigation properties and an `ArgumentNullException` occurres.

Comment: Interesting idea. I now realized that my EDIT was wrong, because EF returned me only the 'main' entity and not the inner collection - it was null, so everything looks fine and working.